# Single motor + Timer. Lift and reverse hand. Single joint robot arm

Tags: motor, design, timer

I need help trying to design a single jointed robot arm that will lift to almost flat on a wall, back down to a right angle position on a timed sequence, repeatedly. It would pause for a few seconds at each position (sketch below)

The hand would weigh approximately 1 kilogram on the end of a 45 cm rod.

I am unskilled and am trying to make it as simple as possible to learn. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

[image: rest position]
[image: lifted position]

Comment: This is not a question, it is a statement.  Which portion(s) are you struggling with?

Comment: I've never done anything like this and I can't decide on how to start.  I'd appreciate any advice on a design to start trying to figure out. i.e.. how to reverse the motor, what kind of timer and other parts to have a look at. Thanks

Comment: You could start with robot kits https://www.google.com/search?q=robot+arm+kit because (as you said) you are new to electronics. Then with the kits, you could learn to control the motor. If it is DC motor, it is easy to control with analog timer. If it is servo motor, you should learn microcontroller programming.

Comment: Thanks @Oka.  I had considered the simple robot arm kits, however they are super expensive to get the kind of lift power I need. Servo motors are very expensive too so DC seems like the go.  How would I go about timing it to the specific angles I require and reversing polarity to make it return?

Comment: @GNC for knowing motor position, you could use rotary encoder https://www.google.com/search?q=rotary+encoder+DC+motor Reversing polarity is done using H-bridge or DPDT switch http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/H-Bridge/H-Bridge-1.html

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking? Are you trying to figure out the size of motor you would need? What components?

There are multiple solutions. Simply, you could attach a motor, probably a small gear-head motor so you could get enough torque, a limit switch or two, and maybe a timer relay to get the pause you are looking for. Simple, cheap and uses off-shelf components.

Do you need the motor to reverse or can the arm just fall down?

You could also build an elegant mechanism like this and have a motor just run continuously. from an electrical perspective, it would be simple:
[Rocker Mechanism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8h9mjKA5SjQ)

Comment: I am asking for both advice on design and on components required. I am very new to electrics.  The arm has to descend at the same speed. That rocker mechanism is beautiful but I'm not sure how to source components like that and would prefer the simple, cheap method.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @GNC You need to more precisely define your requirements and budget. This would help to narrow down the possible designs that you want to select.